# Can you copy a Geometry Node with the inputs remaining the same?

Tags: modifiers, geometry, geometry-nodes

I have an object with a Geometry Node modifier set up on it (it makes the object look damaged/chipped) but when I copy the modifiers to a different object using Ctrl+C it changes the input values meaning I would have to change them all again to give similar results.

Is there a way to copy the Geometry Node modifer and keeping the inputs as they are set up in the original object?

Comment: Select both objects the one with the modifiers as active and use < ctrl + L > link modifiers should work.

Comment: Thats what I have done but the settings are changed when I do.  Thats the issue Im trying to solve as I dont want to have to change them individually each time.

Answer (score 1):

you can select target objects then your original object and press ctrl + L and chose copy modifiers. this might help you.

Comment: Thats what I have done but the settings are changed when I do.  Thats the issue Im trying to solve as I dont want to have to change them individually each time.

Comment: Ignore that and my apologies.  It does work.  Interestingly the command name "Copy modifiers" is the same when you press ctrl + L as when you press ctrl + C but they do different things.  They really should name them differently.